# Flutter: Image not updating

Tags: image, flutter, dart

Im doing a school project with flutter which has a list view of cards. The card has an image, which are stored in maps.
The map is this `Map<String,Image> _imgMap`, the key is the name attribute on the _objectList, which is a dynamic list. I pass the image to another class called Loader, which is a stateful widget that returns a container with circularProgress indicator while the image is loading and returns the image if finished.

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount: _objectList.length,
 itemBuilder: (context,index){
  return Card(
  ...
  Row(
   children<Widget>[
     Container(child: Loader(image: _imgMap[_objectList[index].name]))
    ]
  ...

Loader Class:

class Loader extends StatefulWidget {

  Image image;
  Loader({Key key,this.image}) : super(key : key);

   @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState(image);
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> {
  Image _image;
  bool wait=true;
  _LoaderState(this._image);

  void initState(){
    _image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
      ImageStreamListener(
            (info, call) {
          setState(() {
            wait = false;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return wait ?CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      radius: 50,
      child: simpleCircleLoading() //this is the circleprogress widget,
    ): Image(image: _image.image);
  }

}
```

It works fine the first time, shows the correct image. But after adding a search function which lets the user search by name and then updates the list with only the matching one, the resulting image is the wrong one.

```
void search(String value) {
   if(value.isNotEmpty){
     List<dynamic> result = List<dynamic>();
     _backUp.forEach((obj) { //_backup is the complete list of objects, will not change
       if(obj.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
         result.add(obj);
       }
     });
     setState(() {
       _objectList = result;
     });
   }else {
     setState(() {
       _objectList = _backUp;
     });
   }
 }
```

Examples:

[The initial list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbIJe.jpg)

[Search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aerJg.jpg)

As you can see the information on the card is updating but the image not.The problem is somewhere in the loader class i think since replacing the Loader in the listview with a Image widget fix the error, but i want to show a loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error, i had to pass an UniqueKey to Loader class.